# Laravel 4: Controllers not working, only HomeController

Tags: php, laravel

I have got this "weird" error on a project where I am using L4.

So, if I have the following on the HomeController.php:

```
public function Hi()
{   
echo 'simple test';
}
```

And then call it on a route:

```
Route::get('hi', array('as' => 'hi', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Hi'));
```

It works fine.

However, if I create a new controller on the controllers folder, called MemberController.php and do the exact same `Hi()` function, when I try to call it:

```
Route::get('hi', array('as' => 'hi', 'uses' => 'MemberController@Hi'));
```

It returns...

```
BadMethodCallException
Method [Hi] does not exist.
```

I don't really know what is wrong with this. I have worked before with L4 on other projects, with many controllers, and this never happened.

This server is running on Nginx and not Apache, so no htaccess, but I dont think this is making any difference. L4 is updated to last version. Any thoughts?

Comment: you using Unix or windows ?

Comment: Running Nginx @ Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu is one version of Ubuntu @

Comment: at face value there's no reason it shouldn't work.. maybe post some more context?

Comment: @CrayonViolent I was not seeing anything wrong neither, but I just found the issue. It was related to linux file permission's - could not read the other file apparently - different owner. Seems solved now!

Comment: `/me shakes angry fist at file permissions`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem, it was related to the file permissions.

When installed Laravel through SSH it had full write/read permissions - including the `HomeController.php`. After that, creating other user to have access only to laravel installation made it not necessary permissions which caused any file created by that user on controllers folder not been read properly.

I assume this is barely the explanation - I am not exactly expert on Linux, so hopefully I am not saying nothing wrong - but once I gave the user permissions it started working.

Answer (score -1):

For linux open the \etc\hosts put this line.

```
yourserverip   yourlaravel.com
```

I think that your virtual host is not set in the httpd.conf. You can try this out and see whether it works or not:
For Linux

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourlaravel.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
 </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "/var/www"
   <Directory "/var/www">
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if this was the issue then why would his other controller work?

Comment: VirtualHost is not for NGINX it's for Apache 2.

Comment: okay, but `.htaccess` isn't updated whenever you make a new route/control that's not how routes/controllers work..if achache/.htaccess was screwed, *none* of his stuff would work. Also, what @AntonioCarlosRibeiro said.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I *rarely* downvote), but I suspect the downvote was because of antonio's comment

Comment: @code360, the OP said: `This server is running on Nginx and not Apache, so no htaccess`. VirtualHost is a configuration option to be used in Apache HTTP server, not NGinx, so your answer will never work for him/her.